# Calling Excel from VFP9 on 64-bit machine

Tags: excel, 64-bit, visual-foxpro

I have a VFP9 application which generates Excel files using Automation, starting with :

```
**oExcel = CREATEOBJECT(“Excel.Application”)
oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add()**
. . .
```

Excel 2013 is being used.  The sheet is then populated, formatted and saved .  This works fine on a Windows 7 32-bit machine.  However on a Windows 7 64-bit machine, some instructions fail.  In particular :

```
**oworkbook.SaveAs(<NewFilename>)**
```

fails with the message “Unable to get the SaveAs property of the workbook class”

As a work-around, I have created  before creating the Excel object, and then called :

```
**oworkbook.Save ()**
```

This works.  Have other users experienced this;  are there any other limitations on the use of Excel from VFP when running on a 64-bit machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither oWorkbook.SaveAs() nor oWorkbook.Save() have any problems on a 64 bit machine (I assume you meant windows (7/8/10) 64). Your problem should be something else.

Comment: Thank you Cetin.  You have given a useful pointer.  There is no problem with Save() , as I mentioned;  that has always worked.  But SaveAs() appears to work slightly differently under Excel 2003 and Excel 2013.  If a second parameter, xlExcel8 (=56), is included - to specify .xls output, that seems to throw an error when using Excel 2003;  I will investigate further.  So I think that the problem related to the version of Excel rather than the version of Windows.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Ah that should explain that. Excel 2003 wouldn't recognize xlExcel8 (56) value while 2013 does. Why would you ever want to save as Excel 8. xlWorkbookNormal is fine (or with no format parameters).

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the identical problem but the issue turned out to be that the user had a different version of Excel than I did.  It wasn't the 64 bit vs the 32 bit.  I solved it by defining:

```
  #define xlNormal 39
```

That set the target version of the workbook.  Here is a page about the enumeration:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx

I have also found that, in applications where I am saving up to like 50, that I have to open, set the save flag, do my work then say SaveAs.

Good luck with this :)   Please consider closing this question.  I think you get like two points for that.

Comment: Thanks Missy.  I am happy to close the question.  How can I do that?  - or can you do that for me.

Comment: See the 0?  Under it is a down arrow.  Under that is a check mark that you can see if you hover.  Click on the check mark.  Also click the up arrow on top of the 0s for all the answers to thank everyone who helped you.

Comment: Thanks Missy.  Will do that.  I don't have total recall, but I seem to remember that a member called Cetin responded quite promptly.  I feel I should I thank him for his reply.  Can I do that/

Comment: Absolutely - you should check the answer that was the most helpful to solving your problem.  Then you can uptick the up arrow over the 0 as we all spent time helping you and you can give as many of those away as you like.  There can be no more than one "solution" or check mark.